# Set exact location on page to enter text In Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In Microsoft Word 2010 how can I set the exact spot on a page to type a character or begin text?

WordPerfect had codes to Advance to Position: x.xx" and Advance to Line: x.xx"

I need to fill out a pre-printed form

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if you scanned it in and then created a .pdf form or converted it to word. Do you have those capabilities?

Comment: Perhaps se a textbox instead?